# Flask Event Handler not receiving events from SocketIO

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask, flask-socketio

I've been working on a Flask chat application for the past few days. While trying to add SocketIO, the Flask console displays that it is receiving the message but the event handler in my script is not getting executed.

```
INFO: 71bb17e5b42f4ca18d9e9436d3c42612: Received packet MESSAGE data 2/chat/1,["connected","User has connected!"]
INFO: received event "connected" from 71bb17e5b42f4ca18d9e9436d3c42612 [/chat/1]
INFO: 127.0.0.1 - - [22/Dec/2021 10:11:30] "POST /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=NtYieMW&sid=71bb17e5b42f4ca18d9e9436d3c42612 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
INFO: 71bb17e5b42f4ca18d9e9436d3c42612: Received packet MESSAGE data 2/chat/1,["sentmessage","afeae"]
INFO: received event "sentmessage" from 71bb17e5b42f4ca18d9e9436d3c42612 [/chat/1]
INFO: 127.0.0.1 - - [22/Dec/2021 10:11:31] "POST /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=NtYien3&sid=71bb17e5b42f4ca18d9e9436d3c42612 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

That is the output the flask console is showing me. The browser console outputs nothing.

Here is app.py

```
@socketio.on('connected')
def handleConnect():
    print('Someone connected')
    emit('connected')

@socketio.on('sentmessage')
def handleMessage(msg):
    emit('message', msg, broadcast=True)
    print("handling")
    now = datetime.now()
    current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    db.execute(
        "INSERT INTO messages (user, time, chat, message) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?) ", session["username"], current_time, globalid, msg,
    )
```

And here is the HTML file

```
{% extends "index.html" %}

{% block title %}
{{ chat["name"] }}
{% endblock %}

{% block chat %}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.3.0/socket.io.js" integrity="sha384-HHKD5G6fqvxz/wBz7BFYeOPzBKELGIZv5l5HAECcXD3zdAS6n8OppmPH9ZxGXY0G" crossorigin="anonymous"></script><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    var socket = io.connect('http://127.0.0.1:5000/chat/{{ chat["id"] }}');

    socket.on('connect', function() {
        socket.emit('connected', 'User has connected!');
    });

    socket.on('message', function(msg) {
        var today = new Date();
        var time = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();
        $("#msgsection").append('<div><p><b>{{ user }} - ' + time + '</b></p><p>' + msg + '</p></div>');
        console.log('Received message');
    });

    $('#msgsend').on('click', function() {
        socket.emit('sentmessage', $('#msginput').val());
        $('#msginput').val('');
    });

});
</script>
<div class="chatsection">
    <div class="msgsec" id="msgsection">
        {% for message in messages %}
        <div>
            <p><b>{{ message["user"] }} - {{ message["time"] }}</b></p>
            <p>{{ message["message"] }}</p>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>


    <input class="messageinput" id="msginput" autocomplete="off" required autofocus class="form-control" name="message" placeholder="Enter your message here" type="text"/>
    <button class="messageinput" id="msgsend">Send</button>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your client is connecting on a namespace called `/chat/1`. Your server has handlers that are implemented on the default namespace (which is called `/`). For that reason, events sent from the client reach the server, but they are not dispatched anywhere because you do not have handlers on the namespace the client is using.

As a side note, Flask-SocketIO does not support dynamic namespace names, so you will not be able to connect on `/chat/{{ id }}` or similar paths. The connection URL makes it appear as if this is a URL you are connecting to, but it isn't, the namespace is not part of the actual connection URL. You will need to use a static namespace name (I suggest to just leave it as the default `/`), and then add the chat ID as an argument in your event payload.

Comment: After further research, I came across something called "rooms." Would this be applicable to my problem?

Comment: Yes, rooms can be dynamically added and removed, so that would work.